# Best practice on mocdeling threshold (T) and objective (O) requirements in SysML?

Tags: uml, requirements, sysml, requirements-management

I have considered making a new requirement stereotype for which I can make threshold and objective attributes.  That is fine as far as capturing the requirement goes, but then becomes ugly when trying to do verification.  I'm starting to think they must be captured as separate requirements, which may also be ugly when doing traceability, satisfactions and verifications.

For example, my requirement says "The system shall be no more than 100kg. (T)" and "The system shall be no more than 80kg. (O)"

Tracing this (or a similarly stated requirement) becomes "ugly" when making a test plan and showing which requirement has been satisfied.  If (O) is satisfied, then clearly (T) is also. However, the system will still pass test even though it may fail the verification for (O).  Perhaps it is standard to carry some requirements (O) that are not met.  I am new to this modeling method-so just curious. I wanted to know if there is already a best practice out there. I have been looking and haven't found anything that addresses this.

Comment: Welcome ! Can you define "ugly" and the criteria for an approach that would not be ugly ? Otherwise it would be opinion based and out of scope here.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to model. Maybe an example would help. If you are talking about Performance Requirements like "The system shall have a mass of less than 100 kg", there are two suggestions in the SysML Specification how to model this.

Comment: I adjusted my question to hopefully clarify.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want to model, that a certain performance requirement has two values, a threshold and an objective. Meeting the objective is optional, but meeting the threshold is mandatory. In the test plan, the requirement will be shown as satisfied, if the design meets the threshold. Whether it also meets the objective could be evaluated with a model report, but that is only informative and doesn’t have any effect on the test outcome.

I would create a new stereotype «performance requirement» specializing «abstractRequirement» and «ConstraintBlock» (as described in the SysML specification Annex E.8.2). When you use this Stereotype, you need to add three parameters: `actualMass`, `thresholdMass` and `objectiveMass`. The constraint will be `{actualMass<thresholdMass}`. The `objectiveMass` is then just informative (I have to think it through, how this could get used for reporting).

Another possibility would be to add a `mandatory/optional` field to the performance stereotype and use `optional` for objectives.